# Impossible to search only for Go positions

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

**Description**

It is impossible to search only for Go positions. This is especially true for searches with multiple criteria. For example both of these two searches:

- `https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=golang&allowsremote=true`
- `https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=go&allowsremote=true`

Have these two postings on the frontpage:

- `https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/79848/senior-erlang-infrastructure-engineer-gofactory`
- `https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/97683/senior-ux-designer-wikimedia-foundation`

**Proposed resolution**: Allow searches that actually restrict to the tag go.

Tag searches don't actually restrict tags. The tag is just used as a general search term and result tag matches boosted. This is clearly seen in the following search results, both which specify a specific tag yet have results on that page without that tag:

- `https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/go?sort=p&allowsremote=true`
- `https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/go?pg=27`

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your report. You've hit upon a known limitation of Careers job searches and I appreciate it can be annoying. While I don't have any news to share about resolving this, we are aware and will consider searches restricted by tag as part of future updates to job searching.